# PHP Webdriver - maximize window

Tags: php, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Facebook's [PHP Webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) (Remote Web Driver) and I want to take a screenshot of the 'full page'.

I've tried [executeScript](http://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/classes/RemoteWebDriver.html#method_executeScript) and window.resizeTo(1000,1000) - no luck. I still get a very small window in my screenshot.

Comment: I've found $this->webDriver->manage()->window()->maximize(), but it's not working. Size is always 460x620, and I can't change it.

Answer (score 10):

jbsmooves suggestion is working for Firefox if you load the correct library

```
use \Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverWindow;

$this->webDriver->manage()->window()->maximize();
```

Comment: FYI, the way I finally got this working was this:$options = new \Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions();
   $options->addArguments(array(
     '--window-size=1000,1000',
     '--accept-ssl-certs=true'
   ));

Comment: With Chrome 57 & the latest chromedriver, calling maximize() throws an error for me. To get around this, I pass an option of '--start-maximized' which works regardless of screensize.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
$options->addArguments(array( '--window-size=1000,1000', '--accept-ssl-certs=true' ));
```